# weird text indentation when web scraping with beautifullsoup4 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

## Im trying to web scrape github

---

**This is the code:**

```py
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
  "https://github.com/moom825/Discord-RAT",
  "https://github.com/freyacodes/Lavalink",
  "https://github.com/KagChi/lavalink-railways",
  "https://github.com/KagChi/lavalink-repl",
  "https://github.com/Devoxin/Lavalink.py",
  "https://github.com/karyeet/heroku-lavalink"]



r = req.get(urls[0])

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

title = str(soup.find("p",attrs={"class":"f4 mt-3"}).text)
print(title)
```

---

**When i run the program i don't get any kind of errors but the indentation is very weird**
[image]

**Please anyone help me with this problem**
*Im using [replit](https://replit.com/@devER-M/web-scraping-testing#main.py)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github has [a really good API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api)

You can use `.strip()` after `.text` then it will remove whitespace.

```py
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
  "https://github.com/moom825/Discord-RAT",
  "https://github.com/freyacodes/Lavalink",
  "https://github.com/KagChi/lavalink-railways",
  "https://github.com/KagChi/lavalink-repl",
  "https://github.com/Devoxin/Lavalink.py",
  "https://github.com/karyeet/heroku-lavalink"]



r = req.get(urls[0])

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"lxml")

title = str(soup.find("p",attrs={"class":"f4 mt-3"}).text.strip())
print(title)
```

Comment: ok am dumb
im progging python for 1.5 years and i did not know this!!

Comment: You always lean something - me too

Comment: nice thats how progging works i guess?

Comment: wait i can;t even accept this answer

Comment: it will take 8 mins before we can accept

Comment: how can i use githubs api can u plase say me

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api